# LWC problem -Summer '19 beta release

Tags: lightning-web-components

Me and my team are developing many features using the LWC, before the Summer '19 beta release in sandbox, everything worked well.

But now when we add a LWC in a record page we have the following error:
"The first parameter of loadScript() and loadStyle() must be an LWC component."

This happens because within the LWC we use loadScript and loadStyle methods, the parameters are ok.

Have any of you had this kind of problem?

[image]

Comment: can you add code snippet or minimal viable code for reproduction?

Comment: I simply do the loadScript as documentation @PranayJaiswal

Comment: import style from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/style';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';


renderedCallback() {
 loadStyle(this, style)
                .then(() => { })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error.body.message);
           });    @PranayJaiswal

Comment: I just tried this and it worked, can you try this? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation

Comment: the steps I took were these:
1. lwc creation
2. add the loading of a style and / or lib js
3. add it to a record page
@PranayJaiswal